# Elixir: How to calculate floating point precision > 15?

Tags: elixir

I need to be able to calculate more fractional digits than the `Float` type seems to allow: 15.

```
iex(19)> Float.round(1/7, 15)
0.142857142857143
iex(20)> Float.round(1/7, 16)
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Float.round/2
    (elixir) lib/float.ex:163: Float.round(0.14285714285714285, 16)
```

According to the Pragmatic Programmers' *Programming Elixir* book:

> Floats are IEEE 754 double precision, giving them about 16 digits of accuracy

Is there anything similar to Ruby's `BigDecimal` which allows arbitrary-precision floating point decimal arithmetic?  Or some way to achieve that easily in Elixir?

Comment: Darn. Can you call me curious if I ask why you need so much precision?

Comment: I'm solving Euler Problem #26: Reciprocal Cycles, which requires you to look at the fractional digits of the unit fractions 1/2, 1/3, ... 1/999 to try to find the longest repeating sequence of digits among them. I was able to find the answer with 3000 digits of precision using the Decimal library which Fred the Magic Wonder Dog suggested!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the Decimal library which allows arbitrary precision, but won't have all the available math routines that you'd get with Float.

https://hex.pm/packages/decimal

Decimal works by attempting to preserve as much of the initial precision of the input numbers as possible and only truncates to the precision specified when there are unavoidable round off errors.